# GitLab CI/CD build fails

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup CI/CD for my ASP.NET Core/Angular project. Here's what I have in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0

stages:
    - build
    - test

before_script:
    - "dotnet --info"
    - "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -"
    - "apt-get install -y nodejs"
    - "npm install -g @angular/cli"

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "dotnet build MySolution.sln"

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "dotnet test MySolution.sln"
```

When I push my changes, I get the GitLab build fails with this error:

> EXEC : Build failed with error code: 1
>   [/builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj] EXEC : gyp
>   ERR! stack error : not found: make
>   [/builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj] EXEC :
>   Build failed with error code: 1
>   [/builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj]
>   /builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj(41,5): error
>   MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code -1. 0 Warning(s) 5
>   Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:01:07.46 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

As per tenkmilan's suggestion, I added `apt-get install build-essential` to the `before_script` section of my GitLab CI YAML file. Here's the new `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - "dotnet --info"
  - "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -"
  - "apt-get install -y nodejs"
  - "node --version"
  - "apt-get install -y build-essential"
  - "npm install -g @angular/cli"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "dotnet build MySolution.sln"

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "dotnet test MySolution.sln"
```

But, the build still fails with the following error:

> ../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h(124,26): error G90FC5925: 'class
>   Nan::Persistent' has no member named 'IsNearDeath'
>   [/builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj] EXEC :
>   gyp ERR! stack error : `make` failed with exit code: 2
>   [/builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj] EXEC :
>   Build failed with error code: 1
>   [/builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj]
>   /builds/ataravati/MySolution/MySolution/MySolution.csproj(41,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code -1.
>       42 Warning(s)
>       21 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:05:01.00 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: Can the 5 errors be shown ?

Comment: This is all GitLab shows me.

Comment: Does it compile in your local machine this way? What Node.js version do you have on your local machine? Does it match to the Node.js version what you use on GitLab?

Comment: Yes, it does compile in my local machine. My version of Node.js is `v12.6.0`.

Comment: Could you print out the Node.js version in the CI? I mean after "apt-get install -y nodejs" could you add the command "node --version"? What version is it? If it is the same as you local machine try add following command "apt-get install build-essential" after "node --version".

Comment: @tenkmilan There's no way I can see the output in GitLab, or I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You are able to see the console output of your build on gitlab. Open your repository in the browser, navigate to CI/CD and you will see there your pipeline results. If you open one,  you are able to see the console outputs there.

Comment: @tenkmilan I was able to see the output. The node version is `v12.13.1`.

Comment: Could you please use 12.6.0 in the CI as well? Did you try to add "apt-get install build-essential" as I asked above?

Comment: So, I did add `apt-get install -y build-essential`. Now, the build fails later in the process. How can I install a specific version of Node.js?

Comment: By the way, I updated Node.js on my local machine ti `v12.13.1` and I still build successfully.

Comment: Ok, then your Node.js version is fine on the CI as well, if it works on your local computer with `12.13.1`. As far as I know "apt-get install -y nodejs=12.6.0" but I don't have Linux installed to check it. What is your new error? Could you update the question with it?

Comment: @tenkmilan I’ve updated it, already.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the above-written problem. It seems that while your `npm install` is running the compiling of `node-sass` fails.

I created an example repo with a simple CI:

https://gitlab.com/tenkmilan/angular-dotnet-core-example

The CI configuration is following:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - "dotnet --info"
  - "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -"
  - "apt-get install -y nodejs"
  - "node --version"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "dotnet build my-new-app.csproj"
```

In my example, in the build step I use the `.csproj` file instead of `.sln`. This can be a good starting point for further investigation.